# HTML, PHP Use gmail as my website login

Tags: php, html

I would like user to login as their gmail account (or hotmail, yahoo..etc) as their user login into my website. How could I achieve this? 
Perhaps anything about third party program? Since I am using php and html.
For example: something like stackoverflow where user don't have to register and just login with their email address.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is hard to tell what you really ask. Do you want them to be able to use their email addresses as usernames? Do you want them to be able to log in through external website? Or you just want to require registration confirmation sent to their email address? Please clarify. Also tell us what kind of technology are you using for your site and, probably the most important, **what have you tried so far**?

Comment: Yes i want them to login to their email addresses and come in my website.

Comment: So you want them to be able to: 1) go to your website, 2) click "log in using Google Account", 3) sign in into Google, 4) go back to your website and be authenticated using their Google Account. Correct?

Comment: @Tadeck exactly what i want man!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No idea what type of language you are using. But in PHP all you need is a [**OpenID parser**](http://code.google.com/p/lightopenid/)

Of course, there will be even more coding involved to build the linkage properly. May want to consider giving a tad bit more information on what sort of website your using. (Custom? Wordpress? Drupal? etc)